# Change a lower Panel in preview in VS C#

Tags: c#, panels

Is there any way how do I temporarily hide panel in the preview? I need to work with the second panel which is under the first.

Comment: I hope I cleaned it up for you - make sure I didn't change your intent.

Comment: Webforms?  Winforms?  MVC?  Do you have code samples? What have you tried already?

Comment: Windows Forms. If i can somehow send the pictures ill do it..

Comment: I think you mean "Design View"

Comment: Here: http://ctrlv.cz/z3Kf

Comment: I have many panels.. If ill set on some dock to "fill" i dont see this lower and i cant remodel it.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Design View*, if you have layered containers and would like to select the object underneath the top layer, simply right click on the object on top and VS will automatically give you options to select any object underneath.

This works with any control not just panels:

[image]

Comment: @HanísekSedloň No that would actually change the Z-order. The right click menu will allow you to select the object underneath, which allows you to do things like change properties or resize the control.

Comment: Hm.. when i right click i see: Select "title_Panel", Select "mainMenu_Panel".. for example.. is that it?